# jQuery function to change background color not working

Tags: jquery

```
function ajaxFunction2(){
var chooser2 = $('#chooser2').val();
$('#floatcontainertop').css("background",$('#chooser2').val());
}
```

Could someone please tell me how to fix my above code so that it works.  I have absolutely no knowledge of jquery and I do not know how to call a variable within a function that I have already predefined.  Thanks for the help!

Chooser2 represents a color, i.e. red, blue, yellow, black.

Comment: Should work. What's the value of the color code you're using?

Comment: what is the value of #chooser2?

Comment: maybe try 'background-color'?  Also, use the var chooser2 to make it 4 nanoseconds faster :)

Comment: Why load the value into `var chooser2` and then not use it later?

Comment: the value of chooser2 is the name of a color i.e. blue, black, yellow.

Comment: Alert the value of chooser2, see if you even have a value.

Comment: I know that I do because the value also goes into a database and updates values; I just did not include that part of the function.

Comment: Actually that is very weird.  It alerts me that the value is null, but it updates in the database.  Very strange...

Comment: Thanks Guys, the problem is fixed; I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function ajaxFunction2(){
   var chooser2 = $('#chooser2').val();
   $('#floatcontainertop').css("background",chooser2);
}
```

IF all you need to do is use the variable, then that would be the way, however, if this isn't changing it, it might be that there's another, more subtle, issue?

What behaviour do you get right now?

Comment: Thanks, the problem is fixed; I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to add a pound sign in there...

```
$('#floatcontainertop').css("background", "#" + $('#chooser2').val());
```

But since we don't know what chooser2 returns, I may be wrong. Can you update your answer with a valid response from $('#chooser2').val() and if necessary, I can update my response?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `background-color` instead of `background`.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/SuGCA/)

Try,

```
function ajaxFunction2(){
   var chooser2 = $('#chooser2').val();
   $('#floatcontainertop').css("background-color", chooser2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've put together a fiddle that might be what you're looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/makotosan/dM5kU/2/

Code below for reference:

**Markup**

```
<div id="floatcontainertop" style="width:400px;height:400px"></div>
<select id="chooser2">
    <option>-- Choose color --</option>
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="green">Green</option>
<option value="blue">Blue</option>
<option value="black">Black</option>
</select>
```

​
**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
    $('#chooser2').change(function(){
        var choice = $(this).val();
        $('#floatcontainertop').css("background",choice);
    });
});
```

​